# Minkowski distance code

Tags: java, matlab

I have the java code below which i used to calculate the Minkowski distance,

```
 class Minkowski {
 public static void main( String  [] arg){
    int p=2;
    double [] Mski = new double[5];

    double  [] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5};
    double  [] b = { 6,7,8,9,11};
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Minkowski1(a,b,p);
 }
public static double Minkowski1( double [] a , double [] b, int q)  
{ 
    double sum = 0;
    for(int f = 0; f < a.length; f++){
        sum += Math.pow( Math.abs(a[f] - b[f]),q );
    }
    return Math.pow(sum, 1.0 / q);
 }
```

The Code produce different result from a Minkowski distance matlab code  :

```
for i=1 : 5
    result2(i)=sum(abs(X(i)-Y(i)).^p).^(1/p)
end
the result in matlab is 5 5 5 5 6,and java one is not same
```

any suggestion please

Comment: I think you should be more specific about the difference of the results i.e. for which test case.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is, that

```
1/q=0
```

in java (at least for `q>1`) but

```
1/p!=0
```

in matlab.

So you need to replace the integer division through floating point division and use

```
1.0/q
```

Comment: You should also provide the solution :)

Comment: @ead I changed 1/q to 1.0/q but still have issue with result ??

Comment: @novin and which result is the right one? Are you sure your matlab code is OK? What is the result of java, what is the result of matlab?

Comment: @Ead ,   The matlab one is correct  i used two way to check it the code that i put it here also the  Minkowski  method in matlab  :                                                             /*    for i=1 : 5
            D(i) = pdist2(X(i),Y(i),'minkowski',P)
      end */

Comment: @novin I would say you use `pdist2` in a wrong way, Minkowski distance is a function from R^n->R. You should call `pdist2(X,Y, 'minkowski', P)`. The way you use it, it is R^n->R^n is just abs(X-Y) which is not Minkowski distance. I also would say that your java code yields the right result. You should check it with paper and pencil (don't trust programs you don't fully understand!)